# How to apply for permission to get r_basic_profile api on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

Due to recent LinkedIn changes, I need permission for r_basic_profile api. Can someone share where to apply on LinkedIn to get this? 
Thanks

Comment: This new 'upgrade' of the api has been a total fail. There is no documentation on how to get these privileges. The liteprofile doesn't have a field for something as simple as the vanityName which is ridiculous.